# Issue whille uploading to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, awss3transfermanager

I am trying to upload the image files to aws bucket but I am facing this error some times on the devices,

```
I/AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
                                                                  java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:400)
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:441)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
                                                                      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:280)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:128)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:353)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:533)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:344)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:170)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.java:76)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:537)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:370)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:440)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:76)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4198)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1618)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:174)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:74)
                                                                      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:40)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

But after some time, it shows like,

```
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Identity id is changed
12-12 11:27:25.771 11239-14564/D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
12-12 11:27:25.771 11239-11246/com.amlooking4 I/dalvikvm: Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
12-12 11:27:26.161 11239-14564/D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Saving credentials to SharedPreferences
```

**EDITED :**

Now I am getting this too ,

```
    I/AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: SSL handshake timed out
                                                                      java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out

 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1e5dff8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                  error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:658 0x401d6cf5:0x00000000)
                                                                      at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                                                                      at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)
                                                                        ... 23 more
```

Really getting frustrated because of this misbehaviour, the code is same but some time it executes perfectly, some times it does not and show the above written error.

I am new to aws, I understand that it saves the cognito id into preferneces.

Comment: Your device failed to do SSL handshake with the server. Cognito supports SSLv3 all the way to TLSv1.2. I suggest you run the sample on a different device or emulator.

Comment: Is there any solution to make it working on all the devices

Comment: In theory, it should work on all Android devices. TLSv1 is supported since Android API level 1. However, due to the fragmentation of Android devices, say different API levels, different manufacturer, rooted or not, there is no guarantee it works on all devices. Would you please share your device information?

Comment: It is Samsung note 2 and note 3, lollipop os version.

Comment: Even we are getting the error or moto g 1 st generation but on first hit we get this error but after some time we are hitting to aws, it is uploading

Comment: We are having wifi network which has network securities too actually it is office network. Will this give us any handshake or host unknown exception?

Comment: That's possible. If you are behind a firewall, the connection may be affected. You can use curl to see if you can connect to Cognito. Run the following command in a terminal: curl -Iv https:// cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 or openssl s_client -connect cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443

Comment: I am able to connect with this curl command but by phone still sometimes I am not able to connect.

Comment: Can you please give me any code snippet or blog to refer ?

Comment: Try cellular data or other network. We need to figure out whether it's the network or the SDK that causes the problem.

Comment: Actually, I try with another app which is smug-mug which uses aws to upload the images (from aws official website); that is working fine in the same network. If i use the https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx1E7YWEXPSDRNO/How-To-Use-the-Amazon-SDK-for-Android-to-Upload-Photos-to-Amazon-S3 link, it is also working fine but facing the same not connection issue.

Comment: After curl command, I am getting the below log, It is not connecting first time, then it is connecting; curl -Iv https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.239.22.25...
* Connected to cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (54.239.22.25) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):

Comment: I believe there is some DNS issue with your network. The SDK can't handle it unfortunately. If like you said the device is able to connect to Cognito on the second try, you can probably add some retry logic yourself.

Comment: Yes Yangfan, i put the retry logic now and its working fine now :)

Comment: Awesome. I'll put a note on this issue. If it turns out to be a common issue, I'll address it in the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

add this code to the Utils.Java

```
    private static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredProvider(Context context) {
    if (sCredProvider == null) {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(30000);
        sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context.getApplicationContext(),
                Constants.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
                Regions.fromName(Constants.COGNITO_POOL_REGION),clientConfiguration);
    }
    return sCredProvider;
};
```

and the amazonS3Client suppose to look like this :

```
     public static AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context) {
    if (sS3Client == null) {
        sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getCredProvider(context.getApplicationContext()));
        sS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(Constants.BUCKET_REGION)));

    }
    return sS3Client;
};
```